# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, php, kml

I have spent so much time trying to fix this bug.  I really don't know what the issue is.

http://pastebin.com/wXEHsqeY is where the code is. The error points to leaflet library kml.js but I have not touched this file. The error seems to be coming from lines 366-390 as when I remove them there is no error.

I would really appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

Update: apologies for using the wrong format, please see a more basic example of what Im stuck on.

```
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>

<?php
function getKmlFiles() {

    $folder = 'kml/';
    $filetype = '*.*';
    $files = glob($folder.$filetype);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

        echo '"' . $files[$i].'",';
    }

}
?>

<script>

var kmlArray = [<?php getKmlFiles(); ?>];

console.log(kmlArray);

var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(58.4, 43.0), zoom: 11});
var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
var track = new L.KML("http://localhost/kmllayer/kml.kml", {async: true});
track.on("loaded", function(e) { map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds()); });

map.addLayer(track);
map.addLayer(osm);

    var object ={'THW-UK2 (R)':track};
for (var i=0; i<kmlArray.length; i++) {

    var kmlLayer = new L.KML("http://localhost/kmllayer/" + kmlArray[i] , {async: true});
    object[kmlArray[i]] = kmlLayer;
    map.addLayer(kmlLayer);

kmlLayer.on("loaded", function(e) { 
            map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
         });

         map.addLayer(kmlLayer);

}
console.log(object);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers({}, object, {})); 


</script>




<script type='text/javascript'>

map.on( "zoomend", function( e ) {
    console.log( "zoom level is " + map.getZoom() )
});

map.on( "zoomend", function( e ) {
    zoom = map.getZoom( );
    if ( zoom <= 3 ) {
        alert('zoomed out');
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: -1 it is very hard to help you when you send a link to 500 lines of code. The simplest way is when you create an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please take the time to reduce your example to a *minimal* yet fully functioning demonstration of the problem, and post it here instead of just on a different site like pastebin or jsfiddle.

Comment: my apologies for using the wrong format but I am very new to this and very confused.. so please have some patience with me.  I have included a more basic version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encountered a similar problem, the cause was the kml files were saved as .kmz files but weren't actually zipped.  Issue solved now.

Answer (score 0):

you are opening **php** in your `js file` at line `366`

```
var kmlArray = [<?php getKmlFiles(); ?>];
```

if you want to use the values of php in js file make a variable `global` and call it in your `js` file.

```
<script>
abc = "<?php getKmlFiles(); ?>";
</script>
```

in your js files

```
var kmlArray = abc;
```

Comment: Hi Moeed, Thank you very much for your time.  The whole file is a .php file but references .js files so does your answer still apply? Ill try it out anyway, thank you.